# Why does the number of colors change after saving a bitmap?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, gdi+

I'm creating a single-purpose app that would take an image and save it with some alpha channel adjustments. The adjustments are made with a color matrix and are meant to alter only the alpha channel. I want the otput to be indentical to the original in terms of RGB values.
I'm working with 32-bit PNG images I create using either Photoshop or After Effects. I save/render the files without any compression (at least that's what I'm told).

These are two color matrices that will help me illustrate the issue.

```cs
            ColorMatrix harmlessCm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{
                new float[]{1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[]{0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[]{0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                new float[]{0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}});

            ColorMatrix luminanceToAlphaCm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{
                new float[]{1, 0, 0, .2125f, 0},
                new float[]{0, 1, 0, .7154f, 0},
                new float[]{0, 0, 1, .0721f, 0},
                new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}});
```

Scenario #1. File: 32-bit PNG with no transparent areas, number of colors **5707**.
Applying the `harmlessCm` doesn't have any effect on number of colors.
Applying the `luminanceToAlphaCm` led to decrease in number of colors: 1052.

Scenario #2. File: 32-bit PNG with multiple semi-tranparent areas (same image but without a background), number of colors **6244**.
Applying the `harmlessCm` led to decrease in number of colors: 5990.
Applying the `luminanceToAlphaCm` led to decrease in number of colors: 1470.

Full class:

```cs
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;
using Prism.Commands;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace RGBA_Playground.ViewModels
{
    class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public string Before { get; private set; }
        public Image After { get; private set; } 

        public DelegateCommand UploadCommand { get; }
        public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            UploadCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
            {
                using (var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog())
                {
                    dialog.Multiselect = false;

                    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
                    {
                        var image = dialog.FileName;
                        Before = image;
                        After = GetChangedImage(image);
                        RaisePropertyChanged("Before");
                        RaisePropertyChanged("After");
                    }
                }
            });

            SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
            {
                var changedImage = GetChangedImage(Before);

                using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(changedImage))
                {
                    bm.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName(Before) + "\\" + Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
                }
            });

        private static Bitmap GetChangedImage(string path)
        {
            Bitmap original = new Bitmap(path, false);
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            result.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);

            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{
                new float[]{1, 0, 0, .2125f, 0},
                new float[]{0, 1, 0, .7154f, 0},
                new float[]{0, 0, 1, .0721f, 0},
                new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}});

            using (ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes())
            {
                ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(original, 
                        new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
                        0, 0, 
                        original.Width, 
                        original.Height,
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel, 
                        ia);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I need the output to have the same number of colors in both scenarios. 
Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

I'm sorry if my initial post was confusing. 
Another edit: I forgot to roll back some edits before posting here. I'm using another Bitmap constructor now.
`Bitmap result = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);`
The scenarios and results are edited too.

Comment: 71873 is a smidge beyond 65536, the palette limit for 16 bit color. So I would guess it is downsized to fit into 16 bit colors?

Comment: What is odd is that the very common Version 3 actually supports 32 bit color depth. It is of course possible that the original image was a color depth of 64 bit, only reduced to 71873 by the PGN compression.

Comment: What kind of images are you dealing with? Why are you doing this: `using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(changedImage))` and this: `Bitmap original = new Bitmap(path, false);`? You are instructing to delete the internal ICC/ICM/Exif Tags. Btw, 32bit images don't have a *Palette*.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry but, I completely forgot to mention that this only happens when the source image does some (semi-)transparent areas.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the meaning of 'palette'. I meant it as number of colors.

Comment: Yes, but it's not clear what your trying to do here. You instruct, as already mentioned, to lose the internal ICC informations (if any, of course), then you draw the original image onto a new one lacking these informations (as if those could be preserved completely after this operation, anyway). That ColorMatrix, what should it be doing here? Do you know what it does? Maybe, provide a description of what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jimi I had no intent in losing the internal ICC information tho. How do I keep it? My initial intent was to get the image with preserved RGB channels and an alpha channel that would represent the luminance of RGB values. I'm well aware that the matrix I use in the code above doesn't do anything.

Comment: Allright, but this looks like a way-too-elaborate method to duplicate an image which will never produce a 1:1 sample. Edit your question, explaining what is that you're aiming at.

Comment: @Jimi I edited the post. I hope it's more informative now.

Comment: There's no possbile way that when you apply a transformation to a Bitmap and you draw the results, it will retain the original number of colors. Which is btw irrelevant. A couple of notes: the luminance to alpha matrix is usually applied with neutral colors. So, set all colors to `0` instead of `1` (using `1` you won't get gray-ish standard results). The luminance to alpha matrix should not be applied to semi-transparent images (you'ld generate a great deal of artifacts, compromising the image). Try this set: `lumR = .3086f, lumG = .6094f, lumB = .0820f` instead of the values you're using now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. So why does the number of colors change after saving a *semi-transparent* bitmap?

Seems like class `Graphics` though fast and easy to use, is acutally not that precise when working with semi-transparent images. I managed to get the desired results by using `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` methods. I was avoiding using them for obvious reasons such as low performance, lack of flexibility, etc. But they get the work done.

```cs
        private static Image GetNewImage(string path)
        {
            Bitmap original = new Bitmap(path);
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

            for (int x = 0; x < original.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < original.Height; y++)
                {
                    var px = original.GetPixel(x, y);
                    result.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb((int)GetColorLuminance(px), px.R, px.G, px.B));
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static float GetColorLuminance(Color color)
        {
            var R = color.R * .2125f;
            var G = color.G * .7154f;
            var B = color.B * .0721f;

            return R + G + B;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

There are two ways to publish a image: Uncompressed and compressed via a lossy process. PNG and JPG are the later.* The basic idea is the same as MP3. Nobody really does uncompressed.

(*There are some others like SVG, but that propably will not help you here.)

If I take a screenshoot of my desktop (2560x1440 at 64 color depth) that is 3,686,400 pixel. 64 bits per pixel is 8 bytes per pixel. So this image would be clock around 29,491,200 byte or 29 Megabyte. Nobody wants to move that stuff around the internet or store it.

So compressions like .jpg, .png and .mp3 only pick a select few values from the source and do some really advanced math involving high end human color/sound parsing science to reduce the filesize and hopefully without *human percetible* quality loss. That is how the palette got this odd number that is neither 16, 32 nor 64 bits.

For those reasons formats like .PNG, .JPG and .MP3 are very good for publishing images on the internet (including mails and webpages). Unfortunately that also makes them very bad for further image manipulation, wich is exactly what you do. You should always do manipulation on the bitmap/uncompressed image. If it is a image from a Digital camera, there might even be a pre-processing raw of the data.

And as a final warning: It does not matter how it is compressed during transport or storage. Once you load it for processing or display, all compression steps have to be undone. What you end up is closer to the bitmap you started with, minus some compression artifacts.

Comment: Well, [read up on PNG again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics). It uses *lossless* compression!

Comment: @zett42 Dangit. My memory is not what it used to be.

Comment: Lossy compression is actually rather rare in image formats. More common in video and audio formats, but for images, jpeg and jpeg-2000 are really the only ones I know of.

Comment: @Nyerguds It may be a small part of formats, but those formats are widely used. Exactly because the lossy nature makes them smaler without perceptible quality losses.